# Why doesn't pointsize default to a standard value in webgl?

Tags: google-chrome, glsl, webgl

I have been working on a rendering engine using Webgl and I've noticed inconsistent behavior with the gl.POINTS primitive. On my mac in Chrome, points render and are visible as expected, albeit with a very small default value. When I run the same code on my Windows 10 PC in Chrome, none of the points are visible by default. If I explicitly set point size in the vertex shader (e.g. "gl_PointSize = 1.0"), the points become visible, which suggests that on Windows they are defaulting to an extremely small value, smaller than on my mac.

This is annoying - it introduces unexpected behavior across browsers, and requires that I make a call in my vertex shaders that otherwise would be unnecessary, and which presumably adds overhead to execution.

My question - is this the expected behavior, or have I uncovered a bug in Chrome, and if it is expected - why would this be the default behavior when we aim for standardization across browsers and devices? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [OpenGL ES documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_PointSize.xhtml):

> If gl_PointSize is not written to, its value is **undefined** in subsequent pipeline stages

This means that rendering of points *requires* this variable to be explicitly written, or otherwise results will be undefined.

I believe that defining this value as `0.0` when unspecified (what you see on Windows) can be considered as a good option as WebGL tends to avoid "undefined" in favor of "zero-defined". Chrome on macOS behavior could be found misleading in this case, although obviously drawing points with `1.0` size could be considered as more useful to see something on the screen.

In practice, there is a bit of inconsistency related to `gl_PointSize` in various graphic APIs. For instance, `gl_PointSize` in GLSL program is *optional* within **OpenGL desktop** implementation and point size specified by [`glPointSize()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPointSize.xhtml) will be used by default, which in turns is defined as `1.0` in initial OpenGL state. At the same time, **OpenGL ES 2.0+** (and, hence, **WebGL**) does not define `glPointSize()` method at all, and `gl_PointSize` becomes a mandatory in GLSL code to avoid undefined behavior.

So I believe that experienced different behavior is due to different graphic libraries (layers) used on macOS / Windows for implementing WebGL in Chrome. But as `gl_PointSize` is mandatory for drawing points anyway - there is no point investigating which undefined behavior is better or more correct.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I appreciate it. I didn't realize that glPointSize was not implemented in ES 2.0. That explanation seems to address why this inconsistency wouldn't be handled by the browser. Still, I don't like it! :)